# Math SE Swag designs

Tags: discussion, design, community

Thank you for your [suggestions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/math-stack-exchange-swag-ideas) on the swag ideas. For our math community, we'll be sending top users ([first 2 pages](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) of all time, sorted by rep) **coffee mugs and a writing pad**.

Below is a mockup up of the design.

[image: Math SE swag design]

For the design, I think it's more appropriate to emphasize the math aspect; so I'm using Euler's Identity as the main focus.

Of course, I'm not a mathematician, if you have a suggestion for another equation/theorem, please let me know. Please do keep in mind, the space is somewhat limited, so I prefer nothing too complex(from a design POV).

Comment: I really have no love for that identity... In any case, how did you typeset it? It looks very, very strange. TeX usually does a great job :)

Comment: @mariano can you perhaps suggest another equation that you could perhaps love, in some alternate reality where such things are possible?

Comment: @Jin:  What font is $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ rendered in, in that image?

Comment: I am curious to know: Is there anyone who has not spent some quality math time in the US who appreciates this way of writing Euler's equation?

Comment: @thei I found this form in a [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zApx1UlkpNs). As I said, I'm not a mathematician. This is just for to get the conversation started. @Isaac for the final design I'll be using [STIX font](http://www.stixfonts.org/). The one in the mockup isn't accurate.

Comment: @Jin: [Here](http://2718.us/euler.pdf) is a PDF (STIX font, editable) of the formula rendered with commercial math typesetting software and [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv32X.png) is a PNG of that PDF.  Rendering the same equation using Minion Pro instead of the STIX font yields [this PDF](http://2718.us/euler2.pdf) or [this PNG](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FcGZo.png).

Comment: @Isaac: ($e$ and $i$ and should really be set in an upright font, as all constants... $\pi$ too, but that is less significant as most upright greek fonts are pretty italic)

Comment: @Mariano: Whether constants are set in roman or italics is a style convention—I am inclined to set any alphabetic letters used singly in a mathematical expression in italics to distinguish them from surrounding roman text.  The $\pi$ is set in roman type.

Comment: We also need a much better logo.

Comment: Some of those who added answers to this question, with proposals, are deleting them. Please note that the negative votes only indicate (or are supposed to only indicate) disaggreement with the proposal!

Comment: @Jin: What is the current swag status?

Comment: @Jin: I'd also like to know the current swag status. Do we need to make a final determination on the design? Are t-shirts still going to be offered?

Comment: @Jin: People have asked questions regarding the "Swag" and even I would like to know the status. Why have haven't you replied for the above comments.

Comment: If possible I would like to know if this topic was forgotten.

Comment: We haven't forgotten about this, but the designs proposed here are... Not good for putting on physical items. We're going to go with the usual logo + url, and the standard package of top user items + one additional item to make up for the long wait - stay tuned for details and pics in the next few days.

Answer (score 11):

The picture at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words/8847#8847 seems to have many adepts. (I would redraw it without the arrows if I had to do it again...)

The image can be regenerated in, say, SVG form with the following Mathematica code

```
picture[n_, {i0_, j0_}, cs_] := 
  Graphics[{
    EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.0015], Black}],
    Table[{
      FaceForm[{
      Which[
        {i, j} == {i0, j0}, cs[[4]],
        {i, j} == {i0, 0} || {i, j} == {i0 + j0, 0}, cs[[3]],
        j == 0, cs[[2]], 
        True, cs[[1]]]
        }],
      Disk[
        i/n {1, 0} + j/n {Cos[\[Pi]/3], Sin[\[Pi]/3]},
        1/(2 n + 2)
        ]
      },
      {i, 0, n}, 
      {j, 0, n - i}
      ]
    }
  ];
g = With[{colors = colors = ColorData[14]},
  picture[6, {2, 3}, {colors[4], colors[8], colors[7], colors[3]}]
  ];
Export["picture.svg", g, ImageSize ]
```

which produces (after converting to PNG: I don't seem to be able to upload an SVG image here...) this:

[image]

This is the one I would choose (I cannot vote on it though!)

Comment: Yes, as I said in a previous comment, this picture would look really nice on a coffee mug. Having equations is fine, but coffee mugs are all about the pictures they have. At least I would certainly be willing to buy a coffee mug with this picture on it, but probably wouldn't buy one with Euler's identity on it =P

Comment: A writing pad with Euler's identity looks fine to me. But I do like this picture.

Answer (score 11):

My preference tends towards the geometric and visual rather than text.  So I voted up Mariano's binomial-counting-formula.   But I'd also be keen to take something from an actual MSE thread.  Perhaps the [tessellation thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36834/can-someone-explain-the-math-behind-tessellation):

[image: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36834/can-someone-explain-the-math-behind-tessellation]

Answer (score 4):

This would be nice:

$1+2+3+\cdots = -\frac 1 {12}$

Comment: I like this one because the notation is easy enough for people less experienced with math to go, "That's clearly not true, what's going on here?" and then gives one the opportunity to explain what it really means.

Comment: I would actually prefer an equation that makes mathematical sense and is not just a game with symbols. I never understood people's obsession with that silly "identity". And by the way, how is that better than $1+2+ 4+ 8 + \cdots = -1$ which is much easier to explain and just as silly?

Comment: @Theo: I find values of the analytic continuation of the zeta function more interesting than the identity "1/(1-2)=-1".

Comment: Me too, but then $\zeta(-1) = - \frac{1}{12}$ would be the right thing to write and not the infinite sum. Otherwise I really don't see a difference.

Comment: "$1+2+3+\cdots = -\frac 1 {12}$ under my theory. If I tell you this you will at once point out to me the lunatic asylum as my goal." -[S. Ramanujan's second letter to G.H. Hardy, 27 February 1913](http://books.google.com/books?id=Of5G0r6DQiEC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA53#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Answer (score 3):

Despite being beaten, my favorite math picture are complex dynamics fractals, especially the [Newton fractal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_fractal). A nice rendering is the one in http://cosec.bit.uni-bonn.de/?id=642.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This one:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx = \sqrt{\pi}
$$

Comment: Or perhaps the form I have found very useful $$\large\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi x^2}\;\mathrm{d}x=1$$

Answer (score 2):

The equality
$$196884=196883+1$$
is a [pretty amazing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monstrous_moonshine) one , although somewhat cryptic :)

Answer (score 1):

Two examples of lovable, space ocupying equations:

- Everyone loves the first example given in section 2 of [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogers%E2%80%93Ramanujan_continued_fraction)
- The first equation at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product

Comment: @Theo: There is a mathematical field called "Moonshine theory" and no one told me about it?? Any other alcoholic notions that I am unaware of? ;-)

Comment: I'm in favor of the picture in Mariano's link instead of having Euler's identity. A coffee mug without a nice colorful picture is not very attractive to eye. By the way, [this one](http://www.coffeedetective.com/mr-p-lick-coffee-mug.html) is really funny =P

Comment: @Mariano You should have separated the equations for voting purposes. It would be interesting to know which equation people actually would like on their mugs. I would totally want the moonshine one while the Jacobi triple product has the same problem as the proposed Euler's equation: It has very different presentations and it really rubs you the wrong way if the presentation is counter to your preferred point of view.

Comment: I exploded this into several answers (and now the comments of course don't make much sense...)

Answer (score 1):

From [*Pappus’s theorem and elliptic curves*](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/pappuss-theorem-and-elliptic-curves/) by Terence Tao

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am particular fond of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3134/whats-your-favorite-equation-formula-identity-or-inequality/4680#4680

Answer (score -7):

I would go for:

1. $\displaystyle ZFC+V=L\vdash 2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$ (the continuum hypothesis is true in Godel's constructible universe)
2. $\displaystyle \varnothing\Vdash \text{Math is fun!}$ (the empty condition forces that math is fun!)
3. $\displaystyle 0\to\text{Coffee}\to\text{Mathematician}\to\text{Theorem}\to 0$ (a fatalistic and categorical description of Erdos' theorem about coffee as a short and exact sequence)
4. $\displaystyle \mathbf{Math}\models\text{Fun!}$ (Mathematics is a model for fun!)

And so many others, and I would much rather any other the above over the Euler's formula (which I appreciate and respect, but to quote Sheldon Cooper "What is life without whimsy?")

Comment: Egads, I'd much prefer Euler's identity than any of that. With the possible exception (of a tie) with 3.

Comment: Though come to think of it, you shouldn't be using a short exact sequence. I'm okay with coffee being injective to Mathematicians, and Mathematicians being surjective onto Theorems is not quite okay, but acceptable. But the implication of "Theorem = Mathematician / Coffee" is, I think, the opposite of "Erdos' theorem"...

Comment: @Willie: What can I say... bunch of algebraists in this town. :-P

Comment: Agreed, a short exact sequence seems out of place. Shouldn't you just say something like $\text{Mathematicians} \cong \text{Hom}(\text{Coffee}, \text{Theorems})$?