# Promotional material

Tags: support, community

I attend several conferences per year, and most of them there are people to whom it would be useful to communicate the existence of math.SE. Does SE produce some kind of promotional material? The one thing I have in mind is something like a nice and attractive poster one could give to organizers to display at some visible place, &c.

Comment: Apropos: weren't there plans for math.SE swag? *That* would have made for nice promotional material...

Comment: @J.M., the difference between that and a poster is that I am not going to carry it to a conference :)

Comment: Actually, since SE *is* backed by a company, I wonder if they'd like to get a vendor's table at the JMM, where  TCS, Stats, and Maths (and perhaps more! Th. Physics perhaps) all are participating.

Comment: @WillieWong, JMM is a pretty big event, but I am thinking of smaller ones, like —say— CIMPA schools, q.v.

Answer (score 3):

We [certainly do](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/supporting-community-conferences/)! In fact, we sponsor our community users to go to conferences of their professions or interests. We also create swag and moderator cards too.

An example of [moderator cards](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/878/cross-validated-moderator-cards). I'm also thinking about creating generic site cards too(without personal information), so non-mod users can request them and pass them around to their friends and colleagues.

I know we have a post on the Math.se [swag design](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2491/math-se-swag-designs) idea, but it doesn't seem to have a clear winner yet.

For conferences, I think it may be a good idea to list all the major upcoming conferences and plan ahead of time. That way, we can send swag directly to the conference location so our users don't have to carry them. Or you can pick ONE big conference and iron out some details. For example, our WordPress community's recent [sponsorship proposal](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/817/wordcamp-phoenix-2012-sponsorship-proposal).